# Handlebars, write two variables into the select box, one in select opt and another one as options

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, handlebars.js

Good evening, i´m doing a project where i get data from an api in JSON or Object.
In first variable i get categories of the achievements and in the other one i get the achievements, the thing i want to do is that i have a select box with categories as a optgroup and options as achievements. Here is my code

```
<select>
    {{#each test}}
        <optgroup label="{{this}}"></optgroup>
        {{#each test2}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [MDN  docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup), the `<optgroup>` should wrap it's `<option>`'s.

Also, as it looks like each item in `test` is a string (you're using `{{this}}` as the label value), you will need to access the test2 property in the parent scope using either [`../test2`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) or [`@root` notation](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html) . This is of course assuming this data structure:

```
{
  test: ['category1', 'category2'],
  test2: ['achievement1', 'achievement2', 'achievement3', 'achievement4']
}
```

However, this pattern would not make sense, as for each item in `test`, you would see the same list of `test2`. Thus the code below will assume this data structure, where each category shows it's specific achievements:

```
{
  test: [{
    label: 'category1'
    test2: ['achievement1', 'achievement2']
  }, {
    label: 'category2'
    test2: ['achievement3', 'achievement4']
  }]
}
```

Code:

```
<select>
  {{#each test}}
    <optgroup label="{{this.label}}">
      {{#each test2}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </optgroup>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

### In short, you:

1) needed to wrap the `<option>`'s in their respective `<optgroup>`'s

2) needed to fix either:

a) scope of `test2` list access (assuming each `test` is a string) using `../test2` or `@root/test2`

or

b) manner of accessing the `optgroup` label (assuming each `test` is an object with `label` and `test2` as properties) by using `{{this.label}}`